# Trouble moving data from POST to GET - Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

Pretty new to node/express, working on a weather app that takes in a location from a form to post

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <input id="input" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Search by name or zip code" />
  <button id="button" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I'm able to get the data in the server code, but i need to transfer it to my app.get to use in my API call.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  let input = req.body.city;
  console.log(input);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;

  ..
  code
  ..

  res.render("index", weather_data);
});
```

Comment: Extract the logic from the get mapping into a method that accepts the cityName as an argument.  Call that method from both the get and post.

Comment: I don't know why express programmers forget that it's just Javascript and you can factor out common code into a function that you call from more than one  route.  But, that's what you can do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your form method to `GET` (or omit method attribute, `GET` is default method). So when you submit your form request goes to this route

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  const cityName = req.query.city; // see http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;

  ..
  code
  ..

  res.render("index", weather_data);
});
```

This route `app.post("/",...)` can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, You want to send some sort of data to your server using a post request, then retrieve it using a get request right? 
In that case, you need a database in order to store your data at first.
So you send your data to the server -> store it in the database -> retrieve data from database using a get request.

You can use both SQL or NoSQL databases. 
I suggest you use MongoDB with mongoose module.